# ITK get pixels list from itk::LabelObject

Tags: c++, bounding-box, itk

I have a problem accessing the list of pixels of an itk::LabelObject. 
This LabelObject is obtained with a itk::OrientedBoundingBoxLabelObject (https://github.com/blowekamp/itkOBBLabelMap). The original 3D image is a CBCT Dicom, inside which I'm looking for the position and orientation of a small rectangular marker.

Here is the code which leads to get the itk::LabelObject :

```
typedef short LabelPixelType;
typedef itk::LabelMap<LabelObjectType> LabelMapType;
typedef itk::OrientedBoundingBoxLabelMapFilter<LabelMapType> OBBLabelMapFilter;

typename OBBLabelMapFilter::Pointer toOBBLabelMap = OBBLabelMapFilter::New();
typename ToLabelMapFilterType::Pointer toLabelMap = ToLabelMapFilterType::New();

toOBBLabelMap->SetInput(toLabelMap->GetOutput());
toOBBLabelMap->Update();

LabelObjectType* labelObject = toOBBLabelMap->GetOutput()->GetNthLabelObject(idx);
OBBSize = labelObject->GetOrientedBoundingBoxSize();
```

I guess that accessing the pixels coordinates is possible, as it has to be accessed somehow in order to calculate the bounding boxes, but I didn't manage to do it so far. I tried then to convert the itk::LabelMap (or the LabelObject directly) to a binary image, where I could get to the pixels more easily; and convert and display this markerBinaryImage with VTK, with no more results (I get a black image).

```
typedef itk::LabelMapToBinaryImageFilter<LabelMapType, ImageType> LabelMapToBinaryImageFilterType;
LabelMapToBinaryImageFilterType::Pointer labelImageConverter = LabelMapToBinaryImageFilterType::New();
labelImageConverter->SetInput(toLabelMap->GetOutput());
labelImageConverter->Update();
ImageType::Pointer markerBinaryImage = labelImageConverter->GetOutput();
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to get to this pixels list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it like this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < filter->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfLabelObjects(); ++i) {
    //Obtain the ith label object
    FilterType::OutputImageType::LabelObjectType* labelObject =
        filter->GetOutput()->GetNthLabelObject(i);

    //Then, you may obtain the pixels of each label object like this:
    for(unsigned int pixelId = 0; pixelId < labelObject->Size(); pixelId++) {
        std::cout << labelObject->GetIndex(pixelId);
    }
}
```

This info was obtained from the Insight Journal in the article [Label object representation and manipulation with ITK](http://www.insight-journal.org/browse/publication/176). There, it says that you may obtain the bounding boxes directly using the **Region attribute**. I did not find the way to obtain a region in itk::LabelObject, however here is the inheritance diagram of `itk::LabelObject`:

[image: Inheritance diagram of LabelObject]

If your label object is of type `itk::ShapeLabelObject`, you can use the GetBoundingBox() method to get the bounding box. It has other many methods worth looking at.

*I tried then to convert the itk::LabelMap (...) with no more results (I get a black image).*

A piece of advice here, don't try this complicated stuff to verifyother complicated stuff. You may be failing somewhere else in the chain. Instead, read the pixels like I said before and check out the data. Good Look!

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get this pixels list, thanks to your advices. The reason I don't use directly the region attribute is because it only gives an axis aligned bounding box, and I need a oriented one. This OBB filter works well though.

Comment: Yeah. :) welcome to the AABB problem club! Glad it worked!